# Target Span inside H1 in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change the text color and background color of a span element inside h1.

```
<h1 class="alignfull has-text-align-center has-gutenberg-accent-color has-text-color">Hi, we are <span>Company name.</span> </h1>
```

my css:

```
h1 span{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    
}
```

It works fine in jsfiddle but not on Wordpress. I cleared cache, but no change.
What am I doing wrong?

Can't share the site link, because it's on a local machine.

Comment: You may (probably) have other CSS rules that are more specific than your, and therefore are overriding your rules. Increase the specificity of your rule to try and override the others. E.g. `h1.alignfull.has-text-align-center.has-gutenberg-accent-color.has-text-color > span`

Comment: To add to previous comment, you should start to the heightest parent you can and then you can still add a `!important` but only if you use a specific `id` to be sure to not override other rules